# How i can disable ping request in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ping, ipv4

I want to disable ping request in Ubuntu 16.04 through Terminal. So another host in the network can not know about my system.

Answer (score 2):

you can add following iptable rule to deny the response to ping requests

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -o eth0 -j ACCEPT          
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT     
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT       
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't help.

Every packet your system transmits contains your 48-bit Ethernet address (so systems on the same LAN can respond). Any system on your Local Area Network that you have sent a packet to (or which has its network interface card configured to be promiscuous) will see this address (something like `00:21:9b:22:5c:c2`).  They can `arp -an` to see it.

Any system on some other LAN that you send a packet to has to know your IP Address, again, so it can respond.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question

Comment: @Musher It was an attempt to show that the OP could not achieve "So another host in the network can not know about my system" simply by disabling ICMP PING. It's similar to a kitten hiding its front half only.